# Wondering why xarray takes so much memory when reading my global data, even after indexing ( or slicing) a small area?

Tags: python-xarray

Wondering why xarray takes so much memory when reading my global data, even after indexing ( or slicing) a small area?

```
ERA5_dir=r'H:\ERA5\sfc/'
dask.config.set(**{'array.slicing.split_large_chunks': False})
ERA5_orig=xr.open_mfdataset(ERA5_dir+'*sfc*.nc',parallel=True)
ERA5_raw=ERA5_orig.chunk(chunks={'time':24472,'latitude': 200, 'longitude': 200})
ERA5_raw_cut=ERA5_raw['sst'].sel(longitude=slice(100,120),
             latitude=slice(20,40)).persist()
```

When the above code is run, the memory consumption of the computer will continue to increase until the above code is executed. After that, the memory consumption will be reduced a lot.
I feel that xarray seems to read all the data into memory, and then index or slice the data.
This is very different from the way that NetCDF reads data directly through index, which I understood before.
Is there a problem with my above code operation? Looking forward to your answers, thank you

Comment: I think you might want to pass the `chunks={'time':24472,'latitude': 200, 'longitude': 200}` in the open_mfdataset call instead -- though I'm not entirely sure whether that makes a difference.
By the way, your chunks (24472 * 200 * 200) are still quite large at around 1e9 values; if the dataset contains a single variable of float64, this is equal to 1 GB.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, I have tried to put the chunks={'time':24472,'latitude': 200, 'longitude': 200} in the open_mfdataset call,  although it takes much lower system memory, it takes much more time in the program running.  And if put the chunks (24472 * 200 * 200) outside, according to my watch, it took more than 70GB memory when reading data.  and after the reading, the memory consumption was much lower. Therefore, I wondering whether the xarray read data through indexing or slicing.